# Equivalent of Request.RawUrl for Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I apologize if this a duplicate question. I spent quite a while searching for a similar question but was not able to find one.

I am looking to get the URL of the current PartialView in java-script (in an angular controller). So far, methods I have found all return the existing browser URL:

```
window.href.location;
window.href.pathname;
```

as well as the $location service method in angular. However, I'm looking for a method that returns the same value as the Razor's '@Request.RawUrl' (i.e. the actual Route/URL of the PartialView).

For example, on page '/Category/{categoryId}/Product' I am showing a list of products. I am then using ngDialog and ngInclude to load a PartialView from '/Category/{categoryId}/Product/{productId}/[Whatever]' in a Dialog page.

Then I fire an angular controller in the PartialView. In that controller, I'd like to use the $http service and a URL relative to the PartialView's url. However, this is not possible, since angular is not aware of the PartialView's URL (i.e. the URL that @Request.RawUrl produces if used in the PartialView).

Thank you.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDXmG.jpg)

Comment: There is no equivalent for Javascript. Only your server knows what the path to the partial view is. As far as your Javascript code is concerned, it's all part of the same document. You'll need to pass that path from your server to the client side somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Mike. If I pass @Request.RawUrl to a scope in my controller as a string, is there a way to write a URL relative to that string ? (e.g. using ../ to go  a level up in the URL)? Thanks.

Comment: Of course. Just modify the string as needed to generate a relative path. You could also generate those paths on the server side and pass those along to the client as well.